# Accidentally plugged in USB-C hub cable into Laptop HDMI port. won't turn on

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 7506 2n1 (2021 model). I have a USB c hub cable that I accidentally plugged into my HDMI port. The USB c hub itself was connected to my monitor (not to an outlet). The laptop won't turn on and the led charging indicator doesn't turn on. What should I do? The only thing I've thought of so is to just hold the power button, which doesn't work.

Comment: Did it require force to do this

Comment: A USB-C plug will not easily enter an HDMI port. I suggest you get Dell to service the machine.